# I need to get number series in suffix character

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to get number series in suffix in the cell example given below

> A1 = Recurring12453-001
>
> A2 = Recurring12453-001

Please help me out from this problem

```
function ff() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('O2:O4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('O2:O4').autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('O2:O19'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('O2:O19').activate();
};
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit on what you get vs what you think you should have ?

Comment: In cell"A1" data would be available like "Recurring12453-001" . Last series number should add until A22 like cell "A2" "Recurring12453-002"  "A3" "Recurring12453-003"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any reference to

> SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries

or

> Range.autoFill()

Maybe you could link us a reference ?

Otherwise, here is a (bit ugly) solution which provide you what you looking for :

```
function ff() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var value = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue().split("-");
  var prefix = value[0];
  var suffix = parseInt(value[1]);
  var data = [];
  for(var i = 1; i<=21; i++){
    suffix++;
    data.push(["" + prefix + "-" + ('00' + suffix).slice(-3)]);
  }
  sheet.getRange('A2:A22').setValues(data);  
};
```

Comment: Cell A1 = "recurring999-A-0001"
Cell A2 = "recurring999-A-0002"
Cell A3 = "recurring99-A-0003"  Last serial number should add . I have recorded the script then I found "SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries"

Comment: Here is the spreadsheet link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1krbcVeDSdEGbXKBvz65CTjpltvmBKxubqLlVDopeiq0/edit#gid=0

Comment: If the answer suited you, please consider accept it.

Comment: I think that you misunderstand what I was meaning. Check [how to accept a answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).